# Python 2.7.3 Mergesort Receiving -- "TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len()"

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror, mergesort

I am just about done writing my first mergesort program and am running into trouble when compiling. I have done a bunch of research on this particular error and it seems I'm being non-specific somewhere in my code. I still cannot find said error and would love your help. I have attached the file contents, code, and traceback. Thanks again.

File:

```
999 Message C1 
1033 Message C2 
1054 Message C3 
1056 Message C4 
1086 Message C5
```

Code:

```
DEBUG = True
out = []

logs = open("C:\Users\----\Desktop\logs.txt", mode ="r")

lines = logs.readline()

def debug(s):
    if DEBUG:
        print "DEBUG: ", s

def get_t (line):
    s = line
    s = s.lstrip()
    debug(s)
    i = s.find(" ")
    debug(s)
    s = s[:i]
    return int(s)

def get_lowest_i(logs):
    lowest_i = -1
    for i in range(len(logs)):
        log = logs[i]
        debug("log=" + repr(log))
        if log:
            t = get_t(log[0])
            debug("t=" + repr(t))
            if lowest_i == -1 or t < lowest_t:
                lowest_i = i
                lowest_t = t
    return lowest_i

def get_line_lowest_t(logs):
    while True:
        i = get_lowest_i(logs)
        if i == -1:
            break
        line = logs[i].pop(0)

def mergesort(logs):
    while True:
        line = get_line_lowest_t(logs)
        if line == None:
            break
        out.append(line)
    return out

print mergesort(logs)

f.close()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 50, in <module>
  File "<module1>", line 44, in mergesort
  File "<module1>", line 37, in get_line_lowest_t
  File "<module1>", line 24, in get_lowest_i
TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len()` the error says it all you are trying to read the length of a file object ... being that `logs = open("C:\Users\----\Desktop\logs.txt", mode ="r")` is a file maybe you mean to read the lines of the file and sort that ... `lines = longs.readlines()` `print mergesort(lines)`

Answer (score 1):

file has no method len(). Put it into strings or arrays and then use len()

Answer (score 0):

You are mergesorting the file, not the array called `lines`.